# Jenkins Shared Library - Import a Shared Library inside another

Tags: jenkins, devops, shared-libraries, cicd, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a very large Jenkins shared library (let's call it the parent) that contains CI and CD pipelines, as well as dozens of service pipelines. I would like to move/split the CI and CD pipelines to dedicated shared libraries without change the code inside parent shared library. It seems possible from the documentation, but... will the code currently present in the parent shared library's pipelines need to be refactored?

Comment: The solution could be the _load implicitly_ option inside the Shared Library plugin configuration. It does not require any changes to _jenkinsfile_ code.